# How to get a single file that has been shared with me on OneDrive?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an app that uses the `ms-graph v1.0 API` to write data to excelsheets in my OneDrive. It works with excel files that I uploaded to my drive but doesn't work with excel files that've been shared with me.

I know that I can get a list of all shared files with `me/drive/sharedWithMe` and the file that i want to edit is amongst the files that are being returned.

However, when i try to get one shared drive item using its `driveItem` property `parentReference: driveID` like this: `/drives/{driveID}/items/{itemID}` it returns : `403 - acces denied`.

Here are my permissions:

```
  "user.read",
  "calendars.read",
  "directory.accessasuser.all",
  "files.readwrite.all"
```

I couldn't try the shares path `/shares/{shareID}` because I don't know how to figure out the shareId. It doesn't seem to be among the properties of the item that is returned by `/sharedWithMe`. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by myself.

I got the error

> "message": "Cannot reference a user's drive from another user's personal site"

so I removed the `me/`from the route `me/drives/{driveID}/items/{itemId}` and it worked.